# Bathtub plunger/stopper is attached to chain but won't budge. It is stuck inside the drain blocking the flow of water. How to remove it?

Tags: drain, bathtub, stuck

[image]

My bathtub plunger/stopper is attached to the chain but won't budge. It is stuck inside the drain blocking the flow of water. I tried hot water with dish soap as well as vinegar and baking soda. Should I try CLR? If so, how would I know where to put it and how much since I cannot see the stuck plunger? I can jiggle the chain a little but the plunger/weight won't budge. Maybe I should try putting dish soap down the opening for the lever (instead of the drain) followed by hot water?

Comment: When did it last work ?

Comment: I opened the drain to clean out the hair a couple of days ago. It was draining but a little slow. So I tried using a plunger, and that made it worse. I think the weight got pulled down and blocked the opening. Then I tried hot water/dish soap and baking soda/vinegar. That was when I opened the lever and realized the weight was stuck.

Comment: The water goes down after a while now. I tried jiggling the chain, so maybe it loosened it up a little. Took a quick shower and there were a few inches of water in the tub. But by the time I got dry, it suddenly was gone.

Comment: Have you tried grabbing onto the chain with a pair of pliers and pulling with 5 pounds or so of force? I wouldn't go nuts pulling on it, but I would give it a good steady pull.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Popham. I just tried that. Still won't budge.

Comment: Update: The weight is still stuck, but it is no longer blocking the flow of water. So that's great news, although I would like to get it out and close up the overflow valve. Last night, when the water suddenly drained all at once after my shower, it must have dislodged itself, though I didn't realize it at the time. Tonight, the water went right down the drain.

Comment: Still open to suggestions about what type of lubricant would be safe to use that might dislodge it completely. I would have to pour it down the overflow opening, and anything too liquidy would go right down the drain. But at least I can use the shower now, so no big hurry.

Comment: If you re-attach the drain cover, the angle of the lever will tell you where the weighted stopper is in its functioning vertical range. For all you know it is jammed at or near the top of its range. If you then just leave it alone, you will have a draining tub/shower. Get a rubber disc stopper and use that to seal the tub if you need to fill the tub. These lever action stoppers are way more trouble than they are worth. For showering put in a stainless steel slip in strainer to catch hair before it goes into the drain.

Answer (score 0):

Putting in hot water is just going to make the bit that is stuck, expand (probably more than the pipe as it would have less mass).  And I doubt if soap is going to do anything.

I would try several sessions of CLR, maybe even vinegar.

Comment: Thanks, Rohit. I'm afraid to use CLR until I know where to put it. It might just be a big waste and not even hit the stuck plunger/weight.

Comment: It's late so I'll work on it tomorrow. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: You would pour the CLR down the overflow tube. It would land on the internal stopper. Since water is now draining, the internal stopper must be jammed in an intermediate position, partially open. With the drain cover unscrewed and loose if you would free the stopper, it could conceivably drop down and get jammed again in the closed position. Also if you apply too much force on the chain it could break and then the drain would be stopped up again and have to be replaced. Put the drain cover back on and use a flat rubber disc stopper when you need to fill the tub.